# Не работает цикл for в Паскале

Tags: pascal

Подскажите, в чём проблема?

```
var 
  p, i: real; 
begin
i:= 0.25;
for p := 0 to 16 do
    begin
    i := i * 2;
    end;
writeln('Неверно, ему придётся заплатить: ', i:1:0);
end.
```

Comment: нету точки с запятой?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский нет, просто не записал в вопросе

Comment: `prog.pas(7,5) Error: Ordinal expression expected
prog.pas(8,2) Fatal: Internal error 200611054`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Pascal цикл `For` может итерировать только по `Ordinal`-типам, таким как Integer или перечислимы тип. `real` и прочие типы с плавающей точкой в `for` недопустимы.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло!